# Array declaration to allow any int value as index

Tags: java, arrays, max

Is there any way to declare an int array (arr), such that
an index i can represent any number <= Integer.MAX_VALUE, which cannot be known ahead of time.

So arr[i] will never return an error, as long as the value is <= Integer.MAX_VALUE

I tried `int[] arr = new int[Integer.MAX_VALUE]`, but that requires too much space and is not feasible.

Comment: Arrays are fixed size, so there is no real way around the problem that it would require lots of space. Have you considered using another data Structure like a Map with Integer as Key?

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem, what are you _really_ trying to do?

Comment: @SDJ More like 8 GB. Integer has the size of 4 bytes, ((long) Integer.MAX_VALUE * 4) is 8589934588 (bytes) and that is about 8.5 GB

Comment: @SDJ I believe you're meaning gibibyte, which is shortened GiB

Comment: Thanks everyone, I believe using Maps provides an alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java it is not possible to declare array without size. You don't need to occupy memory for all unused indices using an array. What you need is a Map, which is space efficient for your use case.

```
    Map<Integer, Object> index = new HashMap<>();

    //store
    index.put(1, "Value 1");
    index.put(2, "Value 2");

    //retrieve
    index.get(1); //returns: Value 1
```

Comment: This is a nice idea. In this case, the value returned for a not-yet-added index will be ```null```. As long as that is fine, this should be a good solution as per me. In the case of an array, however, I think ```0``` will be returned for an index that was not specifically set.

Comment: @SreeKumar True. But we could easily get the previous behaviour by using the method `getOrDefault(i, 0)` and return 0 for not available key values of i.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS Agree.